# How to put a value in multiple maps that are nested (phoenix params)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Pure elixir question: How to add a value in maps nested in a main one?
The number of nested maps is not fixed.

In the Phoenix context, the question is how to add value in the params and in the nested params too.

How to go from this:

```
%{
  "fname" => "",
  "lname" => "",
  "addresses" => %{
    "0" => %{
      "address" => ""
    }
  },
  "phone_numbers" => %{
    "0" => %{"number" => ""},
    "1" => %{"number" => ""},
    "2" => %{"number" => ""},
  },
}
```

to:

```
%{
  "account_id" => 2,
  "fname" => "",
  "lname" => "",
  "addresses" => %{
    "0" => %{
      "account_id" => 2,
      "address" => ""
    }
  },
  "phone_numbers" => %{
    "0" => %{"account_id" => 2,"number" => ""},
    "1" => %{"account_id" => 2,"number" => ""},
    "2" => %{"account_id" => 2,"number" => ""},
  },
}
```

The value `"account_id" => 2` was added to the main one and the nested too.

There might be a "Phoenix" way for the params but I'm also trying to think of some kind of 
`Map.merge()` recursion.

EDIT:

- `phone_numbers` and `addresses` are just examples, I'm looking for something generic where the keys of the sub maps and the number of sub maps are not known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the `"account_id"` ending up in the intermediate maps, it might be easiest to just write a recursive function like so:

```elixir
defmodule AccountId do
  def add(map, account_id) do
    for {k, v} <- map, into: %{} do
      if is_map(v) do
        {k, add(v, account_id)}
      else
        {k, v}
      end
    end
    |> Map.merge(%{"account_id" => account_id})
  end
end

AccountId.add(data, 2) |> IO.inspect() # =>
%{
  "account_id" => 2,
  "addresses" => %{
    "0" => %{"account_id" => 2, "address" => ""},
    "account_id" => 2
  },
  "fname" => "",
  "lname" => "",
  "phone_numbers" => %{
    "0" => %{"account_id" => 2, "number" => ""},
    "1" => %{"account_id" => 2, "number" => ""},
    "2" => %{"account_id" => 2, "number" => ""},
    "account_id" => 2
  }
}
```

Comment: That's my current strategy in "pure elixir". I'll test it in the phoenix params context to make sure it works.

Comment: In the phoenix context, it's not working. The changeset of the nested params get lost. Maybe I'm not looking in the right direction. Maybe I should just deconstruct and reconstruct the params map?

Comment: Accepted answer because it answers the question asked. But the `lens` lib works like a charm for the phoenix nested params needs.

Answer (score 1):

Disclosure: author of `lens` here.

I couldn't think of a way to just do it with the built-in `Access`, but you can achieve this with the `lens` lib (https://hex.pm/packages/lens):

```elixir
data = %{
  "fname" => "",
  "lname" => "",
  "addresses" => %{
    "0" => %{
      "address" => ""
    }
  },
  "phone_numbers" => %{
    "0" => %{"number" => ""},
    "1" => %{"number" => ""},
    "2" => %{"number" => ""}
  }
}

data
|> put_in(
  [
    Lens.both(
      Lens.root(),
      Lens.keys(["addresses", "phone_numbers"]) |> Lens.map_values()
    )
    |> Lens.key("account_id")
  ],
  2
)
|> IO.inspect()

# => 
%{
  "account_id" => 2,
  "addresses" => %{"0" => %{"account_id" => 2, "address" => ""}},
  "fname" => "",
  "lname" => "",
  "phone_numbers" => %{
    "0" => %{"account_id" => 2, "number" => ""},
    "1" => %{"account_id" => 2, "number" => ""},
    "2" => %{"account_id" => 2, "number" => ""}
  }
}
```

The

```elixir
Lens.both(
  Lens.root(),
  Lens.keys(["addresses", "phone_numbers"]) |> Lens.map_values()
)
|> Lens.key("account_id")
```

is the key bit. It basically says "take every value under the key account_id FROM ((the whole data) AND (every map value in maps located under the keys addresses and phone_numbers))".

Edit:

OP mentions in a comment that the keys might not be known up-front. You can achieve the same effect without specifying them explicitly with:

```elixir
Lens.both(
  Lens.root(),
  Lens.map_values() |> Lens.filter(&is_map/1) |> Lens.map_values()
)
|> Lens.key("account_id")
```

Comment: Thx for pointing out your lib, definitely useful! I'll have to make some tests and get back to you. `phone_numbers and addresses` were just example, the keys to the sub-maps will be "unknown" I'm trying to figure out a generic way of doing it.

Comment: That should also be supported by the lib with `Lens.filter`, I'll try to add an example in a bit.

Comment: Can you merge your answers as they are both valid? I'll accept it.

Comment: I think they should stay separate, as they present different solutions. You can accept whichever you end up using.